# Probability of a drawing a specific suit and a specific color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

After drawing 5 cards from a standard 52 card deck, what is the probability that the hand will contain:

- 1 diamond
- 1 spade
- Any other red card (diamond or heart)

My first approach was to use a hypergeometric distribution such as:

$$\frac{{13\choose 1}{13\choose 1}{26\choose 1}{???\choose 2}}{52\choose5}$$

However, this doesn't make sense because I have nothing left over to choose the remaining two.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to draw a five-card hand comprised of at least two red cards, at least one of which is a diamond, and at least one spade.

The ways to obtain this are to: Draw from 2 to 4 red cards that are *not all hearts*, and the remainder of the cards drawn are to be black *but not all clubs*.

$$\begin{align} 
&\text{Thus we count:}
\\ &\quad \frac{\sum\limits_{k=2}^4 \bigg({26\choose k}-{13\choose k}\bigg)\bigg({26\choose 5-k}-{13\choose 5-k}\bigg)}{52\choose 5}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{
 \bigg({26\choose 2}-{13\choose 2}\bigg)\bigg({26\choose 3}-{13\choose 3}\bigg)
+\bigg({26\choose 3}-{13\choose 3}\bigg)\bigg({26\choose 2}-{13\choose 2}\bigg)
+\bigg({26\choose 4}-{13\choose 4}\bigg){13\choose 1}
}{52\choose 5}
\\[1ex]
& = \frac{102167}{199920}
\\[1ex]
 & \approx 0.511
\end{align}$$

---

[Addendum]

Your method seems to be trying to count ways to: draw a $\diamondsuit$, draw a $\spadesuit$, draw another red card, draw any two cards.

This is fraught with over counting.   Consider just one example: How many ways would the hand $\rm 10\heartsuit, J\diamondsuit, Q\diamondsuit, K\diamondsuit, A\spadesuit$ be over counted by your method?

$$\begin{array}{llll}
\text{ draw a $\diamondsuit$} &\text{ draw a $\spadesuit$} & \text{ draw another red card} & \text{ draw any two cards }
\\ J\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & 10\heartsuit & Q\diamondsuit, K\diamondsuit
\\ J\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & Q\diamondsuit & K\diamondsuit, 10\heartsuit
\\ J\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & K\diamondsuit & Q\diamondsuit, 10\heartsuit
\\ Q\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & 10\heartsuit & J\diamondsuit, K\diamondsuit
\\ Q\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & J\diamondsuit & K\diamondsuit, 10\heartsuit
\\ Q\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & K\diamondsuit & J\diamondsuit, 10\heartsuit
\\ K\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & 10\heartsuit & Q\diamondsuit, K\diamondsuit
\\ K\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & Q\diamondsuit & J\diamondsuit, 10\heartsuit
\\ K\diamondsuit & A\spadesuit & J\diamondsuit & Q\diamondsuit, 10\heartsuit
\end{array}$$

Comment: Is there a more general way to approach this problem? Could you point me to a resource where I might learn more about how you arrived at your answer? I have never seen the subtraction within the hypergeometric series before.

Comment: Wow, stellar edit! I appreciate you given more information.

Comment: Combinatorics is something of an art. You have to learn to recognise patterns and different methods to count the same thing. Looking for complements is always good start (such as "at least one diamond" and "all hearts" for the red cards). It can often simplify things enormously.